# How to detect fn key press in Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

I want to detect when the user presses the <kbd>fn</kbd> key and do some tasks. I tried the below but it doesn't work:

```
if event.keyCode == kVK_Function {
   print("fn key pressed")
}
```

I have similar code for other keys like left bracket, right bracket, slash, alphabets, and numbers. For these keys, the code, shown above, works fine but it doesn't work for <kbd>fn</kbd> key. I think this is handled differently.

Comment: You mean the `fn` modifier key, not the Function keys `Fn` (F1-F19), right? You're using the wrong symbol / capitalization then (in your blog post, too). To detect any of the `Fn` keys, your keyCode test would work, indeed.

Comment: That's right. Thanks for pointing this out. I've corrected the post and my blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check the `NSEvent`'s [`modifierFlags`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1534405-modifierflags):

```
if event.modifierFlags.contains(.function) {
   print("fn key pressed")
}
```

Comment: This detects if the Fn-key is in a pressed state, not a Fn-key press.

Comment: @Willeke no. I wrote a quick post to better explain how to detect press and release of the Fn key or any of the modifier keys: https://blog.rampatra.com/how-to-detect-fn-key-press-in-swift

Comment: @Willeke You're right, but needs a trivial state machine, and it'll do that, too.

Comment: @Willeke I'm not sure that code is quite right. It'll detect false function key presses/releases when other modifier keys are pressed/released, because those two will trigger `flagsChanged` events. You need to keep a boolean variable that remembers the last fn key state, and compare the new state against that to detect [rising/falling edges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signal_edge).

Comment: @Alexander are you referring to my code in the blog post? I know that presses and releases both would trigger the flagsChanged events, ergo, I am checking the actual flags present in the event.

Comment: @RamPatra Yes, I'm referring to the snippet in that blog post. The print statements might be misleading. They don't detect the press and release events (the rising/falling edges) themselves, they detect whether the fn key is *currently* pressed or released. For example, if you hold `fn`, and then spam the shift key up and down, you'll get `"fn key pressed"` printed every time, despite the fn key having been pressed the entire time

Comment: Ah, yes. Got you. I would update the print statements and add this as a note too to make it explicitly clear.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can detect when the user presses the fn key. Hereunder a solution to distinguish "fn" pressed event from "fn" released event.

```
NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: .flagsChanged, handler: { [weak self] event in

 if event.keyCode == 63 &&
  event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask).contains(.function) {
  print("fn key pressed")
 }

 if event.keyCode == 63 &&
  event.modifierFlags.intersection(.deviceIndependentFlagsMask) == [] {
  print("fn key released")
 }
}
```

By Monitoring the events matching `.flagsChanged`, you get notified for modfier (shift,option,fn, etc) keypress events.
Filtering on keycode (63) ensures the modifier pressed is Fn.